# Migrating an Old project from AS 1.1.0 to AS 2.2 preview 6

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a Lappy running Android studio 1.1.0 and my desktop is running the latest 2.2 preview 6 version. So today I migrated an old project to the new version and it is really bugging me out. It mainly deals with the gradle issues and SDK Buildtool version conflicts.

Firstly I had that 'Proguard' issue and fixed it with the 'minifyEnabled' statement. But after that I am stuck with the SDK Buildtool version problem. I ll paste the **build.Gradle** file below as well as the error logs.

**build.Gradle** file :-

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
} 
 dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

}
```

**Error Logs:-**

> > Information:Gradle tasks [:Gps Uploader:generateDebugSources, :Gps Uploader:mockableAndroidJar, :Gps
> >     Uploader:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :Gps
> >     Uploader:generateDebugAndroidTestSources] Error:Execution failed for
> >     task ':Gps Uploader:processDebugResources'.
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 8.449 secs
> >     Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':Gps
>   Uploader:processDebugResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> Information:2 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See complete
>   output in console

My program is perfectly running on the older version, so thats not an issue.
It will be of great assistance if anyone can point me out to the right direction.

Comment: preview 6 isn't ready, and basing the timing of the last major preview->stable cycle, android studio 2.2 will not come out until next year. I recommend sticking with android 2.1 stable. and just follow the docs and upgrade your gradle file appropriately.

Comment: Did you try to `Sync Project with Grdale Files` or `Clean` the project?

Answer (score 0):

Well after a long night struggle, I finally got the solution to the problem.
The appcompact version was the reason for the conflict.

Changing it from this:-

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])    
}
```

to the new format:-

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

solved the issue for me. Hope this helps. And thanks for the help guys.

Comment: First of all `compileSdkVersion` and major version of support library must be the same. Since the latest version of support library is 24.1.1, `+` won't work with your `compileSdkVersion 19`. Secondly get the latest build tools (24.0.1) independently of anything else. Download it in the SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

Error:Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.10, Gradle 3.x is not supported yet. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\MOMOH\AndroidStudioProjects\NairaHub\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

I got this on my error log and changing the extension as specified fixed it for the particular project.